# Encrypted data not in the encrypted format

Tags: shield, shield-encryption

I have enabled shield encryption for contact name in dev org.

[image]

when I try to create a new record on contact the record is still visible to the users and is not in encrypted format

[image]

I'm missing out something can anyone suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by encrypted format. 
If you expect the data to be masked (meaning being replaced by something like "*****"), this behavior is going away.

As far as the end user is concerned the data will behave the same whether it is encrypted at rest or not.

Comment: then why to use shield encryption if the data is not masked.I'm expecting the data to be masked

Comment: As link provided by @IllusiveBrian's answer mentions, (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_security_pe_masking.htm), mask and encrypt are not the same thing. Main goal of encryption is actually encrypt your data at rest (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_at_rest), so masking was something more related to "View Encrypted Data" permission. which was already removed.

Answer (score 5):

There is no easy answer to your question, starting a new one given that it's much larger that what can fit in a comment.

We took this decision for multiple reasons

1/ The goal of platform encryption is to protect the data at rest and
focuses on attacks such as a hacker stealing a hard drive or an
employee having its credentials compromised. When using platform
encryption neither our DBAs or our site reliability team have a way to
access the encryption key or the data itself other than in ciphertext.

2/ We have multiple ways of controlling access to a logged in user,
such as CRUD, FLS or sharing. We have transaction security and
platform event monitoring that allow you to audit/act upon an end user
attempting something suspicious

3/ Given the complexity of our platform, it has been quite challenging
to implement masking reliably and it sometimes broke features that
rely on data synchronization, salesforce for outlook for instance used
to only work with VED users

4/ Based on our instrumentation, we realized that the ratio between
when we were decrypting vs masking the data was more that 1000 times
more.  These numbers matched the feedback we had from our
customers that they did generally not rely on masking and were giving
VED to every user.

5/ Masking and encrypting at rest are kind of orthogonal problems, you
might want to mask social security numbers regardless whether they're
encrypted in the database. There are thoughts internally about having
masking as a platform feature but that is again a hard problem to
solve. We heard of some customers implementing masking themselves in
the presentation layer

All these combined lead us to sunset masking to make us more effective
at adding more capabilities and compatibilies to platform encryption.
Support for custom formula fields, flow, chatter, wave would have been
way much harder and longer to implement if we had to care about
masking and this is true for the upcoming features that will be
announced at Dreamforce.

All that being said, if masking is truly a must have for your use
case, it is still available with classic encryption.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Spring 17 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_security_pe_masking.htm).  In order to reduce confusion between masked and encrypted data, Salesforce has effectively deprecated the standard use of a mask over data fields.  Fields encrypted with Shield encryption should be hidden from users via means used across all fields, such as field level security.

If you would like the masking behavior (for example, to allow users to see that a field has a value, even if you do not want them to see the value itself), fields encrypted with Shield [support use in formulas](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_security_pe_formula_flow_pb.htm), so you can make a simple formula which shows the end user either a checkbox or "mask" string indicating the underlying field is populated.